# unable to click on checkbox within shadowroot

Tags: ruby, shadow-dom, site-prism

I am writing a test to go through a test flow of a monetary registration.  The registration has Add-ons that appear in different steps that flow.  My goal is to be able to select the checkboxes in the add-on shadow root, so I can get to the next step.  The elements within the shadow root that I'm trying to focus on *seem* like they can be targeted, and they are Enumerators, Arrays, and Hashes.

What I need help with is clicking on the checkbox, but the .click method doesn't work for the elements that I'm targeting.  I don't return an error for .select, but it doesn't seem to do anything either.

As I step through the code, I *think* that I am targeting the correct element(s) which is centered around a checkbox.  But none of the elements I see seem to be classes that can be "clicked" or interacted with.  What I've tried so far:

```
sales_channels_reg.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", sales_channels_reg.regsaver_section.regsaver_testtest.find("#sales-channels-element", visible: false)).find(css: "label[for='addToCart--false']")

Returns:
#<Enumerator: {"shadow-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf"=>"416aad9c-c512-496d-93c3-91c17ec6e27d"}:find(css: label[for='addToCart--false'])>
```

```
- sales_channels_reg.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", sales_channels_reg.regsaver_section.regsaver_testtest.find("#sales-channels-element", visible: false)).find(id: "addToCart--false")

Returns
#<Enumerator: {"shadow-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf"=>"416aad9c-c512-496d-93c3-91c17ec6e27d"}:find(id: addToCart--false)>
```

```
- sales_channels_reg.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", sales_channels_reg.regsaver_section.regsaver_testtest.find("#sales-channels-element", visible: false))

Returns
{"shadow-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf"=>"416aad9c-c512-496d-93c3-91c17ec6e27d"}
```

```
sales_channels_reg.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", sales_channels_reg.regsaver_section.regsaver_testtest.find("#sales-channels-element", visible: false)).class

Returns
Hash
```

```
sales_channels_reg.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", sales_channels_reg.regsaver_section.regsaver_testtest.find("#sales-channels-element", visible: false)).find(id: "addToCart--false").each do |c| puts c, c.class end

Returns
shadow-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf
416aad9c-c512-496d-93c3-91c17ec6e27d
Array
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `call' for {:id=>"addToCart--false"}:Hash
```

```
(byebug) sales_channels_reg.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", sales_channels_reg.regsaver_section.regsaver_testtest.find("#sales-channels-element", visible: false)).find(id: "addToCart--false", :visible => false).click
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `click' for #<Enumerator:0x00007fbeb9195558>

nil
```

Code for what I'm writing

-first file-

```
describe "Showing 4 max add-ons in reg flow", type: :feature, service: "sales_channels1" do
  context "yadda yadda" do
    subject(:sales_channels_reg) { SalesChannelsRegGenerals.new }
    subject(:se_signup_page) { SELogin.new }
    # subject(:gen_reg) { RegistrationHelper.new }
    let(:form_number) { "848624247" }

    it "in test flow does thing" do
      couple of other steps first
      byebug (where I'm at in the code now)
    end
  end
end
```

-different file-

```
require "./spec/page_models/sales_channels_ncsa_section.rb"
require "./spec/page_models/sales_channels_medsaver_section.rb"
require "./spec/page_models/sales_channels_regsaver_section.rb"
require "./spec/page_models/sales_channels_four_addons_section.rb"

class SalesChannelsRegGenerals < SitePrism::Page
  set_url "https://zachpartyka#{SeleniumTest.ngin_site}/register/form/{/form_number}"

  section :regsaver_section, RegSaverSection, "div#siteContainer2"
end
```

-different file-

```
class RegSaverSection < SitePrism::Section
  element :regsaver_testtest, "#pageContentContainer"
end
```

[image: screenshot of html]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those values should be Enumerators, Hashes, etc (unless site-prism is really screwing with Capybaras returns). I'm guessing the reason is that you're using `execute_script` when you should be using `evaluate_script`. `execute_script` shouldn't be used when you expect a return value, and won't unwrap results into element references, `evaluate_script` does.

```
sales_channels_reg.evaluate_script("arguments[0].shadowRoot", ...)
```

Comment: I'm returning the results using evaulate_script.

`sales_channels_reg.evaluate_script("arguments[0].shadowRoot", sales_channels_reg.regsaver_section.regsaver_testtest.find("#sales-channels-element", visible: false)).find(id: "addToCart--false").class`


`Enumerator`

Comment: What version of selenium-webdriver are you using? Make sure it’s 4.x

Comment: That fixed it!  updating gem to selenium-webdriver (4.1.0) returned a `Selenium::WebDriver::ShadowRoot`  The solution ended up being:  `shadowroot = sales_channels_reg.evaluate_script("arguments[0].shadowRoot", sales_channels_reg.regsaver_section.regsaver_testtest.find("#sales-channels-element", visible: false))` /n `shadowroot.find_element(css: "label[for='addToCart--false']").click`